# Drupal 7: calling "menu block" into page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-menu, drupal-blocks

I have the [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module installed; I created a second level menu as block via "add menu block" at the block page, and assigned it to the content area. It displays the menu block at the end of page content, but I need that just after the page title.

How I can I move that menu block to just below page title? Is there any way to call this menu block into page.tpl.php, so I can place it just below page title?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another region in your theme that is shown just under the page title and assign the block to that region.  For information on theming Drupal, see the [Drupal Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Comment: hahaha! you made me feel stupid on myself :) how could not I think of that! just done it, and it works great! thanks!!!! :)